# CSS angled menu with gradient under dropdown issue

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, submenu

I have an angled menu that has a gradient under it that continues all the way to the upper edge.  I also have a subnav that has a different gradient that runs underneath the main nav's gradient. Everything looks right, but when you try to roll over to select from the sub menu drop down, it won't let you and goes to the next item on the main menu. I know this is a z-index issue but I can't figure out how to get it to look and function right.

Thanks in advance for any light you can shed on this problem!!!

I have it up on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jollyrogerd/EwFHY/3/

CSS:

```
    #cssmenu > ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: -95px 0 0 0;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 1;
    float: left;
    display:inline;
}
#cssmenu > ul {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 610px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-24deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-24deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(-24deg);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=2);
}
#cssmenu > ul li {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 610px;
}
#cssmenu > ul li a {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 8px 20px;
    width: 610px;
    font-family:"Myriad Pro", "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: .05em;
    color: #939598;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: lowercase;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 300;
    border-top-left-radius: 20px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
}
#cssmenu > ul li.home>a:hover, #cssmenu > ul li.home:hover>a {
    color: #fff;
    background: #a2d062;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #6e9b31, #a2d062);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, #6e9b31, #a2d062);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #6e9b31, #a2d062);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #6e9b31, #a2d062);
    border-color: transparent;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s linear;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s linear;
    transition: all 0.2s linear;
}
#cssmenu > ul li.productsrev>a:hover, #cssmenu > ul li.productsrev:hover>a {
    color: #fff;
    background: #61c46e;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #2b8a39, #61c46e);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, #2b8a39, #61c46e);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #2b8a39, #61c46e);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #2b8a39, #61c46e);
    border-color: transparent;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s linear;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s linear;
    transition: all 0.2s linear;
}
#cssmenu > ul li.about>a:hover, #cssmenu > ul li.about:hover>a {
    color: #fff;
    background: #459cc7;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #025e8e, #459cc7);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, #025e8e, #459cc7);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #025e8e, #459cc7);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #025e8e, #459cc7);
    border-color: transparent;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s linear;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s linear;
    transition: all 0.2s linear;
}
#cssmenu > ul li.customers>a:hover, #cssmenu > ul li.customers:hover>a {
    color: #fff;
    background: #2e6dab;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #09427a, #2e6dab);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, #09427a, #2e6dab);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #09427a, #2e6dab);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #09427a, #2e6dab);
    border-color: transparent;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s linear;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s linear;
    transition: all 0.2s linear;
}
#cssmenu > ul li.contacts>a:hover, #cssmenu > ul li.contacts:hover>a {
    color: #fff;
    background: #6852a4;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #3d2975, #6852a4);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, #3d2975, #6852a4);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #3d2975, #6852a4);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #3d2975, #6852a4);
    border-color: transparent;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s linear;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s linear;
    transition: all 0.2s linear;
}
#cssmenu > ul ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: 120px;
    top: -9999px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-top: 40px;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
#cssmenu > ul ul.bgsubproducts { 
    background-image: url(http://dev.unnaturallygeisha.com/fellowrobots/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/square-gradient.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    overflow: visible;
    height: 200px;
    margin-top:-40px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    z-index:-100;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s;
}
#cssmenu > ul ul.bgsubabout { 
    background-image: url(http://dev.unnaturallygeisha.com/fellowrobots/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/square-gradient.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    overflow: visible;
    height: 200px;
    margin-top:-40px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    z-index:-100;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s;
}
#cssmenu > ul ul.bgsubcustomers { 
    background-image: url(http://dev.unnaturallygeisha.com/fellowrobots/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/square-gradient.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    overflow: visible;
    height: 200px;
    margin-top:-40px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    z-index:-100;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s;
}
#cssmenu > ul ul li a {
    color: #5d6064;
    background: transparent;
    z-index:1000;
}
#cssmenu > ul ul li.subproducts:hover>a {
    color: #2b8a39;
    background: transparent;
}
.subproducts {
    z-index:1000;
}
#cssmenu > ul ul li.subabout:hover>a {
    color: #025e8e;
    background: transparent;
}
#cssmenu > ul ul li.subcustomers:hover>a {
    color: #09427a;
    background: transparent;
}
 #cssmenu > ul li:hover>ul {
    top: 30px;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id='cssmenu'>
<ul>
    <li class='home'><a href="#" title="Link 1">home</a>

    </li>
    <li class='productsrev'> <a href="#" title="Link 3">products</a>

        <ul class="bgsubproducts">
            <li class='subproducts'><a href="#" title="Link 1">helo</a>

            </li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class='about'><a href="#" title="Link 3">about</a>

    <ul
    class="bgsubproducts">
        <li class='subabout'><a href="#1" title="Link 1">what's a telepresence robot?</a>

        </li>
        <li class='subabout'><a href="#1" title="Link 1">our team</a>

        </li>
        <li class='subabout'><a href="#1" title="Link 1">our robots</a>

        </li>
        <li class='subabout'><a href="#1" title="Link 1">our partners</a>

        </li>
        </ul>
</li>
<li class='customers'><a href="#4" title="Link 4">customers</a>

    <ul class="bgsubproducts">
        <li class='subcustomers'><a href="#1" title="Link 1">driving control panel</a>

        </li>
        <li class='subcustomers'><a href="#1" title="Link 1">instructions</a>

        </li>
        <li class='subcustomers'><a href="#1" title="Link 1">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; setting up your robot</a>

        </li>
        <li class='subcustomers'><a href="#1" title="Link 1">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; driving instructions</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class='contacts'><a href="#" title="Link 5">contacts</a>

</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions:

**Better one:**

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EwFHY/12/)

```
#cssmenu > ul > li.home:hover a,
#cssmenu > ul > li.productsrev:hover a,
#cssmenu > ul > li.about:hover a,
#cssmenu > ul > li.customers:hover a,
#cssmenu > ul > li.contact:hover a {
    z-index:501;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.home > ul,
#cssmenu > ul > li.productsrev > ul,
#cssmenu > ul > li.about > ul,
#cssmenu > ul > li.customers > ul
#cssmenu > ul > li.contact > ul{
    z-index:500;
}
```

**Another one:**

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EwFHY/11/).

I set `#cssmenu > ul`,  `#cssmenu > ul li`, `#cssmenu > ul li a` to all have `width: 90px;` instead of `width: 610px;`

And then I added these two:

```
#cssmenu > ul li ul li,
#cssmenu > ul li ul li a,
#cssmenu > ul >li:hover,
#cssmenu > ul >li:hover > a,
#cssmenu > ul >li > a:hover {
    width:610px;
}
```

Bear with me here: I'm setting the subnav `li` and `a` to be 610px, and setting the top level nav to be `90px` unless it's hovered, then it's set to `610px`.

The problem before was that the top level navigation was overlapping the subnav, because they were all set to that too wide

But due to css-transformations it's animating the growth from 90px to 610px;

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by making the background graphics transparant where the colored gradient lies. So it looks like it is behind but is in reality on top. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
#cssmenu > ul li:not(:hover) {
    z-index: -101;
}
```

This gives all the menu items that are not hovered a `z-index` of -101.
Which means when one is hovered it no longer has a `z-index` of -101 which makes it above the submenu, but the others which are not hovered will still be below the submenu and cannot be hovered from there.

It fixes the problem and it still looks awesome.

That menu looks awesome ;)